# Why isn't the first panel showing in my cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

Sorry for the code dump but Im not sure where is causing the issue. When I click the Round Robin button its supposed to take me to the RoundRobin page (which it does) but then I should be able to click the start and the center panel which is blue should yellow animation panel which is yellow. When I run this, I just see the yellow animation panel and when I click start I get a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout" error.

```
/**
     * @description:scheduling algoritmn visualisation app
     * @version: 1.0
     * @date created: 22/11/2020
     */
    
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import java.net.*; 
    
    public class SchedulingAlgorithms extends JFrame{
        CardLayout cl;
        JPanel contentPane;
        Container deckPanel;
        Image image;
    
        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class SchedulingAlgorithms
         */
        public SchedulingAlgorithms(){
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 658, 336);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
                
            JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            headerPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            headerPanel.setBounds(5, 5, 125, 106);
            contentPane.add(headerPanel);
            
            
            try{
                URL url = new URL("file:C:///Users//alyssa//Scheduling_Animations//icon.png");        
                image=ImageIO.read(url);
                headerPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            
            
            JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
            btnPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            btnPanel.setBounds(5, 111, 125, 181);
            contentPane.add(btnPanel);
            btnPanel.setLayout(null);
            cl= new CardLayout();
        
            JPanel deckPanel = new JPanel();
            deckPanel.setBounds(140, 5, 492, 287);
            contentPane.add(deckPanel);
            deckPanel.setLayout(cl);
                
            JPanel home = new JPanel();
            deckPanel.add(home, "home");
            
            JPanel homePic = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
            home.add(homePic, "homePic");
            
            JLabel instructions1 = new JLabel();
            instructions1.setText("Select a scheduling algorithm to see it's visual representation");
            homePic.add(instructions1);
            
            try{
                URL url = new URL("file:C:///Users//alyssa//Scheduling_Animations//schedule.png");        
                image=ImageIO.read(url);
                homePic.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                
            JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
            deckPanel.add(card1, "rr");
            card1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            
            JLabel txt2= new JLabel();
            txt2.setText("Round Robin: Set the boundaries of the animation");
            card1.add(txt2);
                       
                
            JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
            deckPanel.add(card2, "fcfs");
                
            JTextArea txt3 = new JTextArea();
            txt3.setText("First-Come-First-Served");
            card2.add(txt3);
                
            JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
            deckPanel.add(card3, "sjf");
                
            JTextArea txt4 = new JTextArea();
            txt4.setText("Shortest Job First");
            card3.add(txt4);
                
            JPanel card4 = new JPanel();
            deckPanel.add(card4, "ps");
                
            JTextArea txt5 = new JTextArea();
            txt5.setText("Priority Scheduling");
            card4.add(txt5);
            
            JButton btn0 = new JButton("Home");
            btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(e.getActionCommand()=="Home")
                    cl.show(deckPanel, "home");
                }
            });
            btn0.setBounds(10, 11, 89, 23);
            btnPanel.add(btn0);
                
            JButton btn1 = new JButton("Round Robin");
            btn1.setBounds(10, 45, 89, 23);
            btnPanel.add(btn1);
            
            btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    if(e.getActionCommand()=="Round Robin")
                    cl.show(deckPanel, "rr");
                }
            });
            
                
            JButton btn2 = new JButton("First-Come-First-Served");
            btn2.setBounds(10, 79, 89, 23);
            btnPanel.add(btn2);
            
            btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    if(e.getActionCommand()=="First-Come-First-Served")
                    cl.show(deckPanel, "fcfs");
                }
            });
                
            JButton btn3 = new JButton("Shortest Job First");
            btn3.setBounds(10, 113, 89, 23);
            btnPanel.add(btn3);
        
            btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    if(e.getActionCommand()=="Shortest Job First")
                    cl.show(deckPanel, "sjf");
                }
            });
                
            JButton btn4 = new JButton("Priority Scheduling");
            btn4.setBounds(10, 147, 89, 23);
            btnPanel.add(btn4);
            
            btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    if(e.getActionCommand()=="Priority Scheduling")
                    cl.show(deckPanel, "ps");
                }
            });
            
           JPanel northPanel=new JPanel();
           card1.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
           
           JLabel heading=new JLabel();
           heading.setText("Round Robin.");
           northPanel.add(heading);
           JLabel instructions2= new JLabel();
           instructions2.setText("Set the boundaries of the animation");          
           northPanel.add(instructions2);
           
           JPanel centerPanel=new JPanel();
           centerPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
           card1.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
           centerPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
           
           JPanel animPanel=new JPanel();
           animPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
           centerPanel.add(animPanel,"anim");
           
           
           JPanel southPanel=new JPanel();
           card1.add(southPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
           
           JButton start = new JButton("START");
           start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if(e.getActionCommand()=="START")
                   cl.show(centerPanel, "anim");
               }
           });
           start.setBounds(311, 159, 65, 23);
           southPanel.add(start);           

        }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            try {
                SchedulingAlgorithms frame = new SchedulingAlgorithms();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });
       }
}
```

Comment: You don't know where the issue is.  This is a normal problem, but that doesn't mean you can't find it yourself.  Make a new project, make a simple Swing program, and start adding things in one at a time until the error comes up.  Then you'll know where the error is.  Please see the [mre] page.

Comment: `btnPanel.setLayout(null);` This is likely messing with the layout and thus part of the problem. More generally: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0):

You set the layout for the "deckPanel" using variable "cl" as the reference to the layout manager:

```
deckPanel.setLayout(cl);
```

But then you try to change the card on the "centerPanel":

```
  if(e.getActionCommand()=="START")
     cl.show(centerPanel, "anim");
```

1. You can't share CardLayout references. If you want the "centerPanel" to also use a CardLayout, then you need to keep a separate refence for that layout manager. So you really need  "deckLayout" and "centerLayout" variables for the individual layout managers. This is why variable names should be descriptive, so you know how the variable can be used.
2. Don't use "==" for object comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: I created another CardLayout reference for my canterLayout and used equals to and I still have the same functional error

Comment: @Alyssa, I don't get an Exception. Post your [mre]. So the "mre" should be only code required to replicate the problem. So you don't need all the buttons and you don't need all the panels. You only need the buttons and panels required to demonstrate your problem. This way there is less code to look at and spot the error.